# Trying to Sum up Cross-Tab Data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, pivot, crosstab

I have a table where every ID has one or more places, and each place comes with a count. Places can be repeated within IDs. It is stored in rows like so:

```
ID  ColumnName  DataValue
1   place1  ABC
1   count1  5
2   place1  BEC
2   count1  12
2   place2  CDE
2   count2  6
2   place3  BEC
2   count3  9
3   place1  BBC
3   count1  5
3   place2  BBC
3   count2  4
```

Ultimately, I want a table where every possible place name is its own column, and the count per place per ID is summed up, like so:

```
ID  ABC BEC CDE BBC
1   5   0   0   0
2   0   21  6   0
3   0   0   0   9
```

I don't know the best way to go about this. There are around 50 different possible place names, so specifically listing them out in a query isn't ideal. I know I ultimately have to pivot the data, but I don't know if I should do it before or after I sum up the counts. And whether it's before or after, I haven't been able to figure out how to go about summing it up.

Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated. At this point, I'm having a hard time finding where to even start. I've seen a few posts with similar problems, but nothing quite as convoluted as this.

EDIT: 
Right now I'm working with this to pivot the table, but this leaves me with columns named place1, place2, .... count1, count2,...
and I don't know how to appropriately sum up the counts and make new columns with the place names.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF(
                 (
                     SELECT DISTINCT
                            ','+QUOTENAME(c.[ColumnName])
                     FROM #temp c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
SET @query = 'SELECT [ID], '+@cols+'from (SELECT [ID],
           [DataValue] AS [amount],
           [ColumnName] AS [category]
    FROM #temp
    )x pivot (max(amount) for category in ('+@cols+')) p';
EXECUTE (@query);
```

Comment: Sorry, it's Microsoft SSMS

Comment: Is there a maximum limit of the number of places an ID can have? If so, you just need a pivot. If not, you will need to use dynamic SQL to count the max number of places and then dynamically write the SQL to pivot it.

Comment: Write a query to convert the source data table to a data set with columns: id, place and count.  And then pivot on the result

Comment: There is no limit. Can you go into more detail on how to do the pivot? The pivot code that I have will give me columns labeled place1, place2, place3, ..., count1, count2, count3,.... and I don't know how to sum up counts that have the same place name. In other words, I don't know how to associate place1 with count1, etc  and sum up counts with like places for every ID

Comment: You should add your pivot query to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure is pretty bad. You'll need to normalize your data before you can attempt to pivot it. Try this:

```
;WITH IDs AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        id
        ,ColId = RIGHT(ColumnName, LEN(ColumnName) - 5)
        ,Place = datavalue
    FROM #temp
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(datavalue) = 0
)
,Counts AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        id
        ,ColId = RIGHT(ColumnName, LEN(ColumnName) - 5)
        ,Cnt   = CAST(datavalue AS INT)
    FROM #temp
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(datavalue) = 1
)
SELECT
    piv.id
    ,ABC = ISNULL(piv.ABC, 0)
    ,BEC = ISNULL(piv.BEC, 0)
    ,CDE = ISNULL(piv.CDE, 0)
    ,BBC = ISNULL(piv.BBC, 0)
FROM (SELECT i.id, i.Place, c.Cnt FROM IDs i JOIN Counts c ON c.id = i.id AND c.ColId = i.ColId) src
PIVOT (   SUM(Cnt)
          FOR Place IN ([ABC], [BEC], [CDE], [BBC])
      ) piv;
```

Doing it with dynamic SQL would yield the following:

```
SET @query = 
';WITH IDs AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        id
        ,ColId = RIGHT(ColumnName, LEN(ColumnName) - 5)
        ,Place = datavalue
    FROM #temp
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(datavalue) = 0
)
,Counts AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        id
        ,ColId = RIGHT(ColumnName, LEN(ColumnName) - 5)
        ,Cnt   = CAST(datavalue AS INT)
    FROM #temp
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(datavalue) = 1
)
SELECT [ID], '+@cols+'
FROM 
(
    SELECT i.id, i.Place, c.Cnt 
    FROM IDs i 
    JOIN Counts c ON c.id = i.id AND c.ColId = i.ColId
) src
PIVOT 
(SUM(Cnt) FOR Place IN ('+@cols+')) piv;';
EXECUTE (@query);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to SQL and I was just adopting pieces of code that I saw in other places. The table I have to work with is very screwey I agree, and it's not exactly the way it's stored in the DB, it is the way my colleagues have been pulling the data for other purposes. But I went back into the raw data and I think I may have found another ID that links every place'n' to count'n'.

Comment: Yeah, you really need that link between place'n' and count'n'. My answer is quite hack-y.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
SELECT id,
COALESCE(ABC, 0) AS ABC,
COALESCE(BBC, 0) AS BBC,
COALESCE(BEC, 0) AS BEC,
COALESCE(CDE, 0) AS CDE
FROM
(SELECT id,
 MIN(CASE WHEN columnname LIKE 'place%' THEN datavalue END) AS col,
 CAST(MIN(CASE WHEN columnname LIKE 'count%' THEN datavalue END) AS INT) AS val
 FROM t
 GROUP BY id, RIGHT(columnname, 1)
) src
PIVOT
(SUM(val)
 FOR col in ([ABC], [BBC], [BEC], [CDE])) pvt
```

Tested here: http://rextester.com/XUTJ68690

In the src query, you need to re-format your data, so that you have a unique id and place in each row. From there a pivot will work.

Answer (score 0):

If the count is always immediately after the place, the following query will generate a data set for pivoting.
The result data set before pivoting has the following columns:
id, placename, count

```
select placeTable.id, placeTable.datavalue, countTable.datavalue
from
(select *, row_number() over (order by id, %%physloc%%) as rownum
from test
where isnumeric(datavalue) = 1  
) as countTable

join 

(select *, row_number() over (order by id, %%physloc%%) as rownum
from test
where isnumeric(datavalue) <> 1   
) as placeTable

on countTable.id = placeTable.id and 
   countTable.rownum = placeTable.rownum
```

Tested on sqlfidde mssqlserver: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/701c91/18

Answer (score 0):

Here is one other approach using `PIVOT` operator with dynamic style

```
declare @Col varchar(2000) = '', 
        @Query varchar(2000) = ''

set @Col = stuff( 
                  (select ','+QUOTENAME(DataValue) 
                              from table where isnumeric(DataValue) = 0 
                              group by DataValue for xml path('')),1,1,'')

set @Query = 'select id, '+@Col+' from
            (
             select id, DataValue, 
                    cast((case when isnumeric(DataValue) = 1 then DataValue else lead(DataValue) over (order by id) end) as int) Value 
             from table 
            ) as a
            PIVOT
            (
              sum(Value) for DataValue in ('+@Col+')
            )pvt'

EXECUTE (@Query)
```

Note : I have used `lead()` function to access next rows data if i found character string values and replace with numeric data values

**Result :**

```
id  ABC  BBC  BEC  CDE
1   5    NULL NULL NULL
2   NULL NULL 21   6
3   NULL 9    NULL NULL
```